# Drag drop functionality on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, safari

Does anyone know like if it is possible to implement the drag-drop functionality on the iPad?

Something similar to what is available on;
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

I mean if this can be implemented directly or via some workaround..

Comment: http://html5snippets.com/snippets/17-simple-touch-and-drag-object

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the tags, I'm guessing you're not looking for a native solution. Have you looked into a mobile javascript framework such as Sencha Touch? It seems to have the support you need, and is specifically designed for mobile development:

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

Comment: This is for a web app (or website)...Actually speaking, I am trying to avoid use of any external frameworks within my page (except jQuery)..So is this the only way and is Sencha touch free for commercial use?

Comment: Also I am unable to find any demo on the Sencha touch website with a similar drag/drop feature..Do you have the URL for that..

Comment: You need to use a combination of the many touch events they provide. Here's a sample Solitaire game showing the result (it's included in the source files when you download the framework):
http://touchsolitaire.mobi/

Comment: When you say "touch events", are those provided by Sencha OR are those recognized by Apple Safari..I mean how exactly do those work..and if they are provided by Apple, can we not implement the drag/drop without the need of Sencha?

Comment: No, they're custom events designed to be browser-independent. You could probably write a drag and drop event using only Safari's native support, but why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Do you have any good online references where I can learn more about these events..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch for playing jquery UI features in Ipad or Iphone.

Hope it helps.